# VSIX deploying snippets as part of extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, code-snippets, vsix, vs-extensibility

I'm having issues deploying some code snippets as part of a visual studio extension, they work when i add the extension initially but if i increase the version of the extension and update it from my private gallery it then can't find the snippets at the location. I've got this line in my pkgdef file:

[$RootKey$\Languages\CodeExpansions\CSharp\Paths]
"snip"="$PackageFolder$\Snippets\CSharp\snip"

which sets the registry location initially but when you update the plugin, as opposed to reinstall it, it doesn't update this path. Is there some way to handle this that i am missing without writing code to update this key that runs when the extension is updated (which i'm not currently sure how to do)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working, i'm not entirely sure how but i moved the pkgdef file to the sub-folder itself and then set it to be:

```
[$RootKey$\Languages\CodeExpansions\CSharp\Paths] 
"snip"="$PackageFolder$"
```

This appeared to correct the problem. I'm not entirely sure why my previous path was incorrect as i don't currently have the code to reference but i believe i added an incorrect sub-folder to the path. The main thing that is confusing is why the snippet would be picked up correctly the first time but then only begin to fail on an update to the extension.